# Configure Weblogic Message Queue listener in Websphere

Tags: jms, websphere-8, weblogic12c, spring-jms

I have the below requirement to be met:

Say I have configured a JMS server, a JMS queue and a connection factory in WebLogic. Now, the message sender lies in the same WebLogic instance and able to send messages to the queue successfully. The listener part also works fine if they are in the same WebLogic instance.

Now, my requirement is, the message listener will be part of an entirely different web application deployed on **WebSphere Application Server**. So basically I am trying to listen to a WebLogic queue from a WebLogic server. I have tried to google the solution and found concepts like "Foreign JMS Server" and "Message Bridges" in WebLogic. What I have understood from those is that, it  forwards the incoming message(in my case WebLogic queue) to a remote destination (WebSphere in my case). Then in the remote destination, I can deploy a listener configured as if it is listening to a local JMS queue. Is this understanding correct? In either case, what other options do I have? I don't have any requirement that the message needs to be directly available to my WebSphere queue as long as I am able to read the messages even from a remote message queue. so, if technically possible, the message forwarding is a bit overkill for my need. Any guidance or suggestion on this would be really helpful.

**UPDATES:**

I have tried the exact steps mentioned in both of those articles:
http://middlewaretimes.blogspot.in/2014/06/how-to-configure-weblogic-server-with.html
http://ibswings.blogspot.in/2008/02/integrating-mq-broker-6-with-bea.html

Since I want to use spring JMS, I have written the sender and receiver myself following this [tutorial](http://zachxu.blogspot.in/2010/03/create-weblogic-jms-foreign-server-and.html). However, now I am stuck at the following exception:

```
org.springframework.jms.InvalidDestinationException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'jms/WLReceiverQueue'.; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedInvalidDestinationException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'jms/WLReceiverQueue'.
JMS attempted to perform an MQOPEN, but WebSphere MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error. Check that the specified queue and queue manager are defined correctly.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2085' ('MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME').
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:285)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:496)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:579)
    at InvoiceQueueSender.sendMesage(InvoiceQueueSender.java:23)
    at InvoiceSenderServlet.service(InvoiceSenderServlet.java:17)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedInvalidDestinationException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'jms/WLReceiverQueue'.
JMS attempted to perform an MQOPEN, but WebSphere MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error. Check that the specified queue and queue manager are defined correctly.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:503)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:221)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageProducer.java:1061)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageProducer.java:1019)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.access$800(WMQMessageProducer.java:68)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer$SpiIdentifiedProducerShadow.initialise(WMQMessageProducer.java:765)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.(WMQMessageProducer.java:995)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.createProducer(WMQSession.java:886)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createProducer(JmsSessionImpl.java:1232)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsQueueSessionImpl.createSender(JmsQueueSessionImpl.java:136)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession.createSender(MQQueueSession.java:153)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession.createProducer(MQQueueSession.java:254)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doCreateProducer(JmsTemplate.java:1142)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.createProducer(JmsTemplate.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:600)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$4.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:583)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:493)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2085' ('MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:209)
```

Comment: Have you followed a tutorial like: http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=4739 or http://middlewaretimes.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-configure-weblogic-server-with.html ? You need to show some sort of example or code you have tried, otherwise the question is too broad to be answered. Please edit the question with details

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing kindly refer to the update

Comment: Thanks for the update. If I had to guess, your problem is with the foreign server configuration info. This link http://ibswings.blogspot.in/2008/02/integrating-mq-broker-6-with-bea.html uses a file `file:/C:/MQ-JNDI` to set up the foreign server connection URL... how have you set up the foreign server jndi and url? Have you tried including a user/password? It looks like weblogic fails to forward on the message because it can't find your websphere server

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing: Ok, so found something interesting here. If I change the queue name created in the Websphere MQ same as the name of the local Jndi name specified in weblogic server, then I am able to send the messages to the queue successfully i.e. going by the steps mentioned in the tutorial, if I change the name of the "MQReceiverQueue" to "jms/WLReceiverQueue" it works fine. So it seems the lookup is happening based on the local jndi name and not based on the remote jndi name. Any guess on that?

Comment: I think you found the solution, which was just a naming error for local vs. remote. Maybe one of the tutorials has the insructions backwards/it was just a mistake.